# flutter_config is not reading from .env file when proguard is enable

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to get flutter_config to work along with proguard but when I switch `minifyEnabled true`, my flutter code is not reading from the .env file I have in the root directory but instead is returning null. Flutter_config is working fine with my android code but not in flutter code.

here is my build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
        developmentdebug: ".env",
        developmentrelease: ".env",
        productiondebug: ".env",
        productionrelease: ".env",
]

apply from: project(':flutter_config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "<App-ID>"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `-keep class com.YourPackageName.BuildConfig { *; }` to `android/app/proguard-rules.pro`

Comment: Much appreciated, this helped a lot